# Is there a better way to apply patch from one branch to another for SVN?

Tags: svn

IntelliJ has this nice integrated "shelve" command that can kind of do this more easily, but still a bit difficult to apply to different branches in one go.

I always manually creating a patch, copying it to the different branch's working folder, then apply. This is sometimes error prone.

What do you guys do?

---

To clarify a bit (and thanks to Carlos's first answer)

I thought merge will push all changes for a file to your target branch. However, if I have branched at rev 10, made changes 11 and 12 to a set of files, some of which overlap. And I only want to port fix rev 12 to my RC branch, I can't simply use svn merge since that will bring over 11 as well.  If there's a way around this in svn merge, please correct me.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually do an "svn merge" with TortoiseSVN is quite easy.

You can check here: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re16.html
and here: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html

Comment: +1, what `svn merge` does - beside managing merging metadata - is calculate the diff and apply it